# Why does my registration form not work ? (Django Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am creating a website using Django. Somehow I cannot register as a user as I always get the following error message:

UnboundLocalError at /register/
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

**views.py**

*Register a new user*

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    pform = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and pform. is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        profile = pform.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to login')
        return redirect('login')
else:
    context = {
        'form': UserRegisterForm,
        'p_form': UserProfileForm
    }
return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

*Creating a profile*

```
@login_required
    def profile(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
            p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
    
            if u_form.is_valid() and p_form. is_valid():
                u_form.save()
                p_form.save()
                messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
                return redirect('profile')
    
        elif request.method == 'DELETE':
            return redirect('startup-home')
    
        else:
            u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
            p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    
        context = {
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
        }
        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

**register.html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
        <div class="content-section">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="border-top pt-3">
                <small class="text-muted">Already have an Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a></small>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Does anyone have an idea why my context is false or won't be accepted ?

UPDATE: [image]

[image: even when I change it to "p_form", I still get the same error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing context in else statement so that's why it won't accepting.

Change this:

```
else:
    context = {
        'form': UserRegisterForm,
        'p_form': UserProfileForm
    }
```

To this:

```
context = {
    'form': form,
    'p_form': p_form
}
```

And your views look like this:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
       p_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
          user = form.save()
          profile = pform.save(commit=False)
          profile.user = user
          profile.save()
          username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
          messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to login')
          return redirect('login')
    else: 
         form = UserRegisterForm()
         p_form = UserProfileForm()     #Here you made mistake
    context = {
      'form': form,
      'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

Comment: Now I get the following Error Message when I register:Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: I have updated context try that

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated my post with a screenshot. This is how I supposed to change it, right? Or did I misunderstood you? Seems like something is missing after the brackets

Comment: According your screenshot of that register view, you need to change the pform to p_form in register view because in your context you have added p_form

Comment: And also you got indentation error and context must not be inside if statement

Comment: just look closely to the context in my answer where i added

Comment: I did changed it to p_form but I still get the same error ( I added a new screenshot)

Comment: You got indentation error. To solve this, select context and hit shift+tab

Comment: IT WORKED. I just found out that it really was only the indentation. Thank you Manoj!!!!! for being so patient with me

Comment: Great finally you solved it happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
context = {
    'form': UserRegisterForm,
    'p_form': UserProfileForm
}
```

you are returning the actual classes, not an instance of the classes, which would be your forms.

Also, you are not actually setting `context` in the first part of the `if`, so that needs moving outside the conditional entirely.

You need to return what you've defined:

```
    else: 
         form = UserRegisterForm()
         pform = UserProfileForm()   
    
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'p_form': pform,
    }
```

Note that the difference is in the brackets ...

- `UserProfileForm` is just the class object.
- `UserProfileForm()` calls the class to get an instance of the class.